# Having trouble using react-moveable with NEXTjs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to solve this issue for the last few hours. I'm able to use react-moveable just fine with a simple node.js app. When I try to use the same module inside of a NEXTjs app, it throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined`

Here is the issue replicated:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-ramanujan-ttqh3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

As far as I can tell, it looks like I'm trying to render something on the server-side that should be on the client-side. Not sure what the solution is though...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the module is not SSR-ready, and it's trying to read navigator.userAgent

You can try moving your logic to another component and using next/dynamic to dynamically import it setting ssr to false:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// ...
// other stuff, imports, etc
// ...

const MoveableNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('./MoveableWrapper'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <div>Loading Moveable...</div>,
});
```